# execute a sql file whose name is generated dynamically during runtime in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, execute

I have a plsql file, in which i have a loop from 1 to 100.

```
For i=1, q1.sql should be executed.
For i=2, q2.sql should be executed.
.
.
.
For i=100, q100.sql should be executed.
```

How to implement this apart from using If/Else?

Comment: This is a peculiar way of doing things.  You need to explain why you're doing it this way.  But the main problem is that is is *very hard* to run SQL PLus scripts from PL/SQL.  If you're wedded to generating SQL*Plus scripts you need to manage everything from an shell script on the OS.

Comment: This is what I am trying to implement in plsql. I want to generate a random number between 1 to 100 and execute that query. Eg. if the number generated is 10, I want to execute q10.sql. Now, I want to run this (random number + execute the query) say 1000 times. under one sqlplus session. Letme know if there are any workarounds.

Comment: Normally, under a sql session, we can execute a plsql block and in that block, we can specify the sql files we need to execute as @filename.sql. But, in this scenario the file name is based on the random number that is generated. Hence, it is not static. one of the choice is to have an if-else-if ladder but I am searching for an alternative.